# References of Array and Objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, oop

In java array carries reference to a memory location and objects does that too. So when we create an array of objects, does that mean that the array carries reference to more references?

I asked this question to my professor, but didn't quite understand what he explained.

Comment: Your question mentions 'reference to a memory location'. That's not really a thing in Java - references aren't exactly the same as C/C++ pointers. If an array has objects in it then it is really holding references to those objects. Could you give an example with some code of what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
  Object[] array = new Object[10];
```

the variable `array` contains a reference. This reference points to an array object, which can contain 10 references. These references are all `null` at the point that the array is created.

Once you write:

```
  array[0] = new Object();
```

`array[0]` now contains a reference to an `Object` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Suppose you have code like this:

```
 class Foo { ... 
     public int getBar () { ... 
     public void setBar (int bat) { ...
```

Now, elsewhere you have code like this:

```
 Foo [] glorblarr = new Foo [12]; 
 Foo flarg = new Foo ();
 ...  
 flarg.setBar (100);
 glorblarr [7] = flarg;
 System.out.println (flarg.getBar () + "  " + glorblarr [7].getBar ());
 glorblar [7].setBar (987);
 System.out.println (flarg.getBar () + "  " + glorBlarr [7].getBar ());
```

You should expect the output to be this:

```
  100  100
  987  987
```

At this point, `globarr [7]` refers to the same Object as `flarg`. That is, one Object, but it is accessible via two names / references. At least until one of the references is changed to point to something else (or `null`), one is an alias for the other.